# Embedding jw player to wordpress does not accepting hight

Tags: video, video-streaming, jwplayer

I have embedded JWPlayer through a WordPress plugin installation and created a custom player for it. When I apply the player to my page, it ignores height and it displays always in equal dimensions (width / height).

Because of this I uninstalled the plugin, reinstalled it and I even reinstalled WordPress to get rid of the problem, but no hope. Can anyone tell me what the issue may be?

The link for the code is:

http://www.jasdigitalmedia.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

I'm had the same problem.  It needs to have a special div with the id="jwplayer-1-div" and class="your custom name" and which is empty except nested inside of it is another div called id="jwplayer-1" and it is empty.

Now it takes some jwplayer javascript to get it to work, so your best bet is to use shorttag codes to put it all in there for you.

I used a special function in the loop theme, like this:

echo jwplayer_tag_callback("[jwplayer config='libplayer' file='$movie' image='$preview']");

Now it is using my custom player.

I'm not quite done, because I don't want to embed it I just want a link.